# Is there a registry key to disable sounds on the SAP GUI?

Tags: audio, gui, sap

Is there a registry key to disable sounds on the SAP GUI?

I know that [sounds can be disabled manually](http://howtosap.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/disable-sap-gui-sound-or-notification.html), but I want to be able to set the default value to 'off' on people's PC's.

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack exchange started as I am sick of the SCN Q/A forums. Check it out here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/SAP/General/Appearance/Sound

Set this to "off"